# How can I display Facebook comments for specific posts in my React (Next.js) app?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, next.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm trying to implement Facebook comments in my React (Next.js) app.

However, I can't display comments on specific posts.

For [this page](https://www.facebook.com/oleksiy.chernyshov), I see [this first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwfM3.png).

For [this page](https://www.facebook.com/oleksiy.chernyshov/posts/716357920494507), I see nothing.

This is my code:

```
const CommentsFacebook: FC<PropsType> = ({ pageUrl, numpost = 5, width = '' }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //@ts-ignore
    if (window.FB) {
      //@ts-ignore
      window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
    const fbSDK = (d, s, id) => {
      let js;
      const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_ID}`;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    };
    fbSDK(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <div
        className="fb-comments"
        data-href={'https://www.facebook.com/oleksiy.chernyshov/posts/716357920494507'}
        data-colorscheme="dark"
        data-width="100%"
        data-numposts="2"
        data-order-by="reverse_time"
      ></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(CommentsFacebook);
```

How can I display comments on specific posts?